# getting confused with parameters in linear algebra's problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so I got this problem:

```
4x+8y+7z+3cw=3b
x+2y+2z+cw=b
2x+4y+2z+(c-1)w=b
```

and I'm doin' the first steps as follow:

```
4 8 7 3c   3b
1 2 2 c    b
2 4 2 c-1  b
```

Row2->2Row2 -Row3:

```
4 8 7 3c    3b
0 0 2 c+1   b
2 4 2 c-1   b
```

Row3->2Row3-Row1:

```
4 8 7 3c      3b
0 0 2 c+1     b
0 0 -3 -c-2  -b
```

Row1->1/4 Row1
Row2->Row2+Row3

```
1 2 7/4 3c/4   3b/4
0 0 1 -2c-3   -2b
0 0 -3 -c-2   -b
```

Row3->Row3+3Row2

```
1 2 7/4 3c/4  3b/4
0 0 1 -2c-3   -2b
0 0 0 -3c-5   -3b
```

Row2->Row2-Row3

```
1 2 7/4 3c/4   3b/4
0 0 1 c+2      b
0 0 0 -3c-5    -3b
```

and here I'm getting completely out... I know I need to say something like: if c is not 5/3 then Row3->1/-3c-5 Row3

but then when I start to describe each one of the x, y, z, w it's getting to some gibberish:

```
w=-3b/3c+5
z=b+(c+2)(3b)/3c+5
x=3b/4-2y-7/4(b+(c+2)(3b)/3c+5)
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I solve something like that. I don't think it suppose to be so.

Thanks!

Comment: Assume that there is feasible solution, then if $c=-3/5$, we must have $b=0$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, Solomon. But I just thought I must go this way or another to the situation when c isn't equal -3/5... and of course then i will assume that c is -3/5

Comment: So I assume your computations are correct. And we want to study the case that $c\neq -5/3$, then what we should do is to finish the process to find the reduced row echelon form, say first clear the $c+2$ and so on...

Comment: Hm... Didn't really get what you're saying, because i don't think there's a way to get row canonical form here... damn, that's getting more confusing, lol

Comment: Actually, I think you probably get some wrong computation, perhaps you can subsitute them to check is it correct.

Comment: where do you see wrong computation? :|

Comment: Ok, Solomon, I got what u were talking about :) Thanks! I'm goin' further with assuming that c=/= -2 so it won't get 0 and so on till i reach all possible answers. but if u seen an mistake with computation plz do tell me, i can't see it :/